# numerical integration using a pointer to a function always return 0

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to use the function that I was given by my professor to calculate the integral of a polynomial function (polynomial such as: ax^2+bx+c). the function is:

```
double numbericalIntegration(double a ,double b ,double(*func)(double)){
    double delta = (b - a)/32;
    double sum=0, x;
    for(x= a+0.5*delta; x<b ; x+=delta)
    {
        sum+=(*func)(x);
    }
    return sum*delta;
}
```

I changed a lot in order to integrate a polynomial function. but I was get the answer 0. why is that? and I'd  appreciate if anybody tried to correct my work. my code is:

```
double integralPoly(double x, double a, double b, double c){
    return (a*pow(x,3))/3 +(b*pow(x,2))/2 + (c*x);
}

double numbericalIntegration(double a ,double b ,double(*func)(double,double,double,double), double firstNum, double secondNum, double thirdNum){
    double delta = (b - a)/32;
    double sum=0, x;
    for(x= a+0.5*delta; x<b ; x+=delta)
    {
        sum+=(*func)(x, firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum);
    }
        return sum*delta;
}

int main()
{
    double (*func)(double,double,double,double);
    func = integralPoly;
    double sum = numbericalIntegration(2,4,func,1,1,4);
    printf("sum = %d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You try to print a `double` with the format `%d`, which is for `int`. You need one of `%e`, `%f` or `%g` here and you should also print a newline `\n` after the number. Switch on your compiler warnings in order to learn about such format mismatches.

Comment: Do you know what is the expected output for those numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change two things. First your polynomial function doesn't make any sense. You said it needs to be in the form of `ax^2+bx+c` but in your code polynomial is `(ax^3)/3+(bx^2)/2+c*x`. Your function should be:

```
double integralPoly(double x, double a, double b, double c){
    return (a*pow(x,2)) +(b*x) + c;
}
```

Also you need to change your printf. `%d` is integer type specifier and you need double, so you need to use `%f` for example:

```
printf("sum = %f",sum);
```

Now the output of your program is:

```
sum = 32.666016
```

which is correct for your parameters.